# Is is possible to overwrite file you are working on?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I was wondering if you can overwrite file you are working on in bash? I have words sorted and im looping through it. When i find the word i want i use && to save it to file2 and i would like to use || to delete it from file1 but on next iteration i want to use the updated version of a file.

```
while read word; do
    [[string1==string2]] && echo something || delete word from file
    done < file1 > file2
```

I tried to use `|| sed -i -e 's/$word//g' file1` but it doesnt work. It creates files with weird names and not updating the current file.
Any ideas?

Comment: You have `$word` inside single quotes, so it will not do variable substitution there.

Comment: So what do I do here? I tried putting all in double quotes and $word in single quotes and it doesnt work.

Comment: `$word` cannot be in single quotes.  What you are trying to do?  What are `string1` and `string2`?

Comment: Lets say I have 20 same words in a file. Loop takes 1 on each iteration and i want to compare it with other reversed string. If its the same save it to one file if its not delete all occurrences of it in a file updating it so on next iteration it will not take other 19 words which are the same but it will take 21st one.

Comment: "Reversed string"?

Comment: [[ "$word" == $(rev <<< "$word") ]] && echo "$word" and it saves it if its the same to another file but if its not i want all occurencies of this word to be deleted from file before next iteration so i won't take the same word which was false in last iteration to rev and checking.

Comment: You cannot delete from `file1` while feeding the `while` loop as shown (e.g. `while ...; do ..<del from file1>.. done < file1`) because the *inode* for the file will change.

Comment: That is what i thought. i was just curious and I have another question to this one. Can i maybe make it to to use 2 files instead? When 1 is overwritten while loop will read 2 and it will switch the files every time condition is false? It would make program much faster even when it will have to switch between files instead of doing the same thing for n strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can do these in wholesale other than one by one

```
grep -xvFf keys file > file_keys_removed

grep -xFf keys file > file_keys_only
```

or at one shot with `awk`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} 
             {f=FILENAME "_keys_" (($0 in a)?"only":"removed"); 
              print > f}' keys file
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how i can put it in my loop when the word == word | rev is false

Comment: The whole point is you don't need an explicit loop.  For example `awk` will go though all records and do the comparison one by one for you.  Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  It always helps to have sample input output files to explain the desired action and to test the suggested scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
for word in $( cat file1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u ); do
   drow=$( rev <<< "$word" )
   if [ "$word" == "$drow" ]; then
       echo something >> file2
       echo "$word" >> tmp$$
   fi
done
mv tmp$$ file1
```

The above code will result in file1's not being in its original order.  It will be sorted.